# Use Media Services to deliver DRM licenses: is this supported in v3?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, drm

Using Azure Media Services v2, you could use Azure just for storing content keys and issuing DRM licences *but* have all the rest (packaging, streaming, delivery) done on-premise.

That was documented in this guide so it was officially supported e.g

*"... The following diagram shows the main steps you need to take to use Media Services to deliver PlayReady and/or Widevine licenses but do the rest with your on-premises servers ..."*

*"... you can stream from your own streaming server"*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-keys-and-licenses

In reviewing the documentation for v3, I can't see an equivalent to this. So my question is: is it still possible to do what is documented above using v3?

The only examples I've seen in v3 tie the key to a streaming locator. Which I believe would force you to use Azure's dynamic packaging and content delivery/CDN. Has the decision been made for that reason? Or is it in fact still supported?

I guess if v2 is going to continue to be supported indefinitely, it's less of an issue. But it would be better to migrate to v3 if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Media Services V3 support deliver DRM licenses as V2.

Answer (score 0):

**After comparing the differences between the v2 and v3 versions, I think the following document is what you want and can achieve the same function.**

[Media Services v3 with Widevine license template overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/drm-widevine-license-template-concept)

**In addition, I think the v2 version will eventually need to be upgraded to the v3 version.The following is the official statement.**

[Update your Azure Media Services REST API and SDKs to v3 by 29 February 2024](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-release-notes#update-your-azure-media-services-rest-api-and-sdks-to-v3-by-29-february-2024)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question about whether it will be supported indefinitely (no). As for the main part, about whether you can do the same flow in v3, that link doesn't make that clear. As far as I read it, still, you can't. For example in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/architecture-design-multi-drm-system it again describes "StreamingLocator describes content key/IV used for encryption, and streaming URLs" tying the streaming locator to the key. Whereas in v2, you could store a key and so obtain a licence, independently. So could package and deliver yourself

Comment: @coder_uk Then it should not be supported. You can rasie a support to confirm.